# Postgres index for a conditional join

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have 3 tables (all simplified here)

```
job (id int, type char(1))
data (job_id int, owner int, creator int, value int)
user (id int)
```

My query is

```
select user.id, job.id, sum(data.value)
from job
join data on job.id = data.job_id
join user on case job.type when 'O' then data.owner else data.creator end = user.id
group by user.id, job.id
```

How do I create an index in Postgres which caters for the case statement in the join?

Job would have maybe a dozen rows, users 1000s and data millions.

Thanks

Comment: The condition needs values from two different tables. There is no way you can create an index for that. An index can only be defined on expressions using columns from the table you define the index for.

Comment: Btw: it's CASE _expression_ not a statement.

Comment: Was afraid that was the case.. back to the drawing board then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What's the execution plan from your query?

Comment: Thanks for looking but am refactoring to duplicate the rows in data with a new "type" column. One row for owner, one for creator. Much easier to add index to and has sped the query up by a factor of over 1000....! Thanks

Comment: Change that to two queries with a `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you don't need the table "user" to get the results:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN job.type = '0' THEN DATA.OWNER
        ELSE DATA.creator
    END AS user_id,
    job.ID,
    DATA.VALUE
FROM
    job
    JOIN DATA ON job.ID = DATA.job_id -- indexes on the id's
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Edit: Assumption: There is a foreign key between "data" and "user" that checks if a user exists.

Comment: Alas, there is no key between them. Data actually just contains the emails of the users which I need to join on to get the ids.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this isn't possible. Solved my issue by refactoring code to add a row into data for each type, along with a new "type" column and then indexed against this.